# Ошибка автоинкрементируемое поле MS SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

не работает INSERT INTO в таблицу, хотя стоит автоинкрементируемое поле.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Раньше все работало нормально, а теперь нужно дополнительно вводить новую команду: SET IDENTITY_INSERT Doctor ON;

Comment: лучше код и ошибки приводить не скриншотами, а текстом

Comment: И к ошибке надо непременно прикладывать запрос, который привёл к этой ошибке.